# How to find the source table rows used by a big complex query

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a huge Oracle SQL query in our project which is using many views and tables for source data.

Is there any way to find the list of rows fetched from each source table by this big query when I run it?

Basically what we are trying to do is to create the bare minimum number of rows in the source tables so that the outer most big query returns at least a single record.

I have tried to run the smaller queries individually. But it is really time consuming and tedious. So I was wondering if there is a smarter way of doing this.

Comment: "so that the outer most big query returns at least a single record" ... are you just trying to search for the existence of a single matching row?

Comment: Check the execution plan. It should give you at least a hint how many rows are selected on which table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fine Grained Access Control. Here is how you might do it:

Step 1: Create a table to hold the list of rowids (i.e., the results you are looking for in this exercise)

```
CREATE TABLE matt_selected_rowids ( row_id rowid );
```

Step 2: Create a FGAC handler that will add a predicate whenever a base table is selected.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE matt_fgac_handler IS
  FUNCTION record_rowid ( p_rowid rowid ) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC;
  FUNCTION add_rowid_predicate (d1 varchar2, d2 varchar2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END matt_fgac_handler;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY matt_fgac_handler IS

  FUNCTION record_rowid ( p_rowid rowid ) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO matt_selected_rowids( row_id ) values ( p_rowid );
    COMMIT;
    RETURN -1;
  END record_rowid;



  FUNCTION add_rowid_predicate (d1 varchar2, d2 varchar2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 'matt_fgac_handler.record_rowid (rowid) = -1';
  END add_rowid_predicate;
END matt_fgac_handler;
```

Step 3: Add a policy to each base table used by your view (you can get the list by using DBA_DEPENDENCIES recursively, or just doing an explain plan and eyeballing it).

E.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE matt_table ( a number, b varchar2(80) );
CREATE INDEX matt_table_n1 on matt_table(a);

insert into matt_table values (1,'A');
insert into matt_table values (2,'B');
insert into matt_table values (3,'C');
insert into matt_table values (3,'D');
insert into matt_table values (3,'E');
insert into matt_table values (3,'F');
insert into matt_table values (4,'G');
insert into matt_table values (4,'H');
COMMIT;
BEGIN
  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY('APPS','MATT_TABLE','record_rowids_policy', NULL, 'matt_fgac_handler.add_rowid_predicate', 'select');
END;
```

So, at this point, whenever a user selects from my table, Oracle is automatically going to add a condition that calls my `record_rowid` function for each rowid.

For example:

```
delete from matt_selected_rowids;
SELECT /*+ INDEX */ * FROM matt_table where a = 2;
-- This gives your the rowids selected...
select r.row_id, o.object_name from matt_selected_rowids r left join dba_objects o on o.object_id =dbms_rowid.rowid_object(row_id);
```